# Homogeneous Linear Systems

Tags: linear-algebra

For a nonhomogeneous system of 2012 equations in 1999 unknowns, answer the following three questions:

- Can the system be inconsistent?
- Can the system have infinitely many solutions?
- Can the system have a unique solution?

Comment: What have you tried? (And for that matter, what have you learned?) See http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/1803/how-to-ask-a-homework-question for why I ask.

Comment: What do you know about linear systems?

Comment: Honestly not much. I'm hoping to learn from answers

Comment: This really is incredibly similar to your other question here http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/227608/linear-algebra-and-augmented-matrix/227610#227610 Would it not be better to ask one question and see if you get the idea?

Comment: I did and it didn't work.

Comment: Right. What do you mean exactly by "it didn't work"?

Comment: Simplify! Consider, say 6 equations and 3 variables.

Comment: Heck, consider 3 equations in 2 unknowns. But don't try anything simpler than that, unless you're willing to accept $0x=0$ as an equation in one unknown.

Answer (score 1):

There's homogeneous in the title and nonhomogeneous in the text.  In either case, we have a $2012 \times 1999$ matrix $A$.  We are looking for solutions to $A\mathbf{x}=\mathbf{0}$ (homogeneous) or $A\mathbf{x}=\mathbf{b}$ where $\mathbf{b} \neq \mathbf{0}$ (inhomogeneous).

### Homogeneous

We immediately have $A\mathbf{0}=\mathbf{0}$, so $\mathbf{x}=\mathbf{0}$ is a solution, so the system is consistent.  (In fact, all homogeneous systems of linear equations are consistent due to the all-$0$ solution.)

By definition, it will have infinitely many solutions if and only if the [null space](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kernel_%28linear_algebra%29) of $A$ is non-trivial, i.e., if and only if the rank of $A$ is less than $1999$ (by the [Rank-Nullity Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rank%E2%80%93nullity_theorem)).  One example is when $[A|\mathbf{0}]$ corresponds to the system of equations 
\begin{align*}
x_1 &=0 \\
2x_1 &=0 \\
3x_1 &=0 \\
\vdots \\
2012x_1 &=0.
\end{align*}

By definition, it will have a unique solution (and this solution must be the zero solution) if and only if the null space of $A$ is trivial, i.e., if and only if the rank of $A$ is equal to $1999$.  One example is when $A$ has $1$'s on the main diagonal and $0$'s elsewhere, which has rank $1999$.  This is when $[A|\mathbf{0}]$ corresponds to the system of equations
\begin{align*}
x_1 &=0 \\
x_2 &=0 \\
\vdots \\
x_{1999} &=0 \\
0 &=0 \\
\vdots \\
0 &=0. \\
\end{align*}

### Inhomogeneous

It can be inconsistent: e.g. when $[A|\mathbf{b}]$ corresponds to the system of equations
\begin{align*}
x_1+x_2+\cdots+x_{1999} &=1 \\
x_1+x_2+\cdots+x_{1999} &=2 \\
\vdots \\
x_1+x_2+\cdots+x_{1999} &=2012. \\
\end{align*}

It can have infinitely many solutions: e.g. when $[A|\mathbf{b}]$ corresponds to the system of equations
\begin{align*}
x_1 &=1 \\
2x_1 &= 2 \\
3x_1 &= 3 \\
\vdots \\
2012x_1 &= 2012. \\
\end{align*}

It can have a unique solution: e.g. when $[A|\mathbf{b}]$ corresponds to the system of equations
\begin{align*}
x_1 &=1 \\
x_2 &=1 \\
\vdots \\
x_{1999} &=1 \\
0 &=0 \\
\vdots \\
0 &=0. \\
\end{align*}

---

*Note*: The answers to the second part changes if we work over finite fields.